# Selenium IDE generate code not using WebDriverWait.Until

Tags: selenium, nunit, selenium-ide

When generating `NUnit` code from selenium ide, wait commands like `clickAndWait` generate an awkward pattern using a loop.

Wouldn't it be better to use a `WebDriverWait.until`?

Or am I getting something wrong?

UPDATE:
Sorry, wrote from memory, the code i was referring to is on the `waitForElement`command and not `clickAndWait`.

This is the code i'm referring to:

```
// waitForElementPresent | id=id |             
for (int second = 0; ; second++)
{
    if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
    try
    {
        if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("id"))) break;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}    

private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Reading various guides and other answers, it seems to me that a better solution would be this one:

```
// waitForElementPresent | id=id |             
if (!WaitForElementPresent(By.Id("id"))) { Assert.Fail(); }

private bool WaitForElementPresent(By by)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by something wrong?? Could you expalin more with sample code??

Comment: Clarified the question, there was also an error, i was referring to clickAndWait type commands while it was on waitForElement commands

Comment: And is the problem with this??? I mean is there any error??

Comment: The code works of course, but the second function seems clearer to me, making it easiear to mantain a test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `WebDriverWait` is the better approach to wait for element exist, But instead of creating own custom `ExpectedConditions` you should use selenium provided [`ExpectedConditions.ElementExists`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementExists.htm) function to wait until element exist as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
IWebElement el =  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ExpectedConditions, didn't know about that. Do you know if you can change the standard exporter?

Comment: @SilverXXX I'm sorry..i didn't understand what are you asking??

Comment: Right now, if we have a test in selenium ide and use "Export test case as... -> c# / NUnit / WebDriver" the first version with a cycle inside the test method get generated. Is there a way to change it so that the second one is generated? (or even adding a new export)